# 404 failed to fetch package

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 14.10

Okay, so I'm pretty new at this so I may not be giving you the right amount of infomation but I hope this is suffecent in helping me.

I am running Ubuntu 14.10LTS (even thought my /etc/apt/source.list says something about 13.10) and I just strated getting this "404 not found" and "failed to fetch", I've tried doing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` `grep -E 'archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`
 but they haven't worked, hell I think the last two things made it worse.

`terminal read out`

```
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy Release
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy/main amd64 Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy/restricted amd64 Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy/main i386 Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy/restricted i386 Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy/main Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1) saucy/restricted Translation-en
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                         

Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-updates InRelease                 

Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed InRelease                

Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                       
Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release.gpg               
Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed Release.gpg              
Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease                   
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [1,204 B]                
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease                               
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,220 B]                 
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release.gpg                             
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release                                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Sources                         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner i386 Packages                   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en_US               
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en                  
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                             
Get:3 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources [549 B]               
Get:4 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages [604 B]        
Get:5 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages [804 B]         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb InRelease                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:6 http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages [58.9 kB]    
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en                  
Get:7 http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/games amd64 Packages [73.1 kB]   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:8 http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US [59.7 kB] 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/games Translation-en               
Get:9 https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main amd64 Packages            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:10 https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/games Translation-en               
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main amd64 Packages              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps i386 Packages                 
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Err http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/games i386 Packages                
404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.25.125 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/games Translation-en               
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps Translation-en                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US           
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps Translation-en                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/games Translation-en_US            
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/games Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                       
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release [15.1 kB]                       
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                        
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release [15.1 kB]                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Sources                
404  Not Found
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Sources          
404  Not Found
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Sources            
404  Not Found
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Sources          
404  Not Found
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages         
404  Not Found
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages   
404  Not Found
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages     
404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages   
404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages          
404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages    
404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages      
404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages    
404  Not Found
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en_US      
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en         
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en   
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en   
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en_US  
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en     
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages [7,100 B]           
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages [7,100 B]            
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en [2,624 B]           
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources [17.2 kB]                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Sources                               
404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 126 kB in 36s (3,431 B/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/utopic-getdeb/games/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.25.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`/etc/apt/source.list`

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb-src http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb-src http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe
deb-src http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb-src http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-proposed universe main multiverse restricted
```

Comment: you are using `saucy` mirrors for `utopic`. `saucy` is an EOL distro, you may need to remove these mirrors. try to use `InRelease` instead of `Realese`?  and why are you fetching `utopic` packages from _old-releases.ubuntu.com_? Maybe you messed your _sources.list_ a bit up?

Comment: Ah, It is a duplicate

Comment: Don't use saucy mirrors! utopic and saucy is EOL distros!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may be best that you reset your sources.list to the default. Replace what's in `/etc/apt/sources.list` entirely with:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
```

Then do `sudo apt-get update` and the 404's should stop.

Backup sources.list before you do something destructive like an in-place sed replace on it in the future (e.g. `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`.

Hope that helps!

NOTE: I used http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ to generate the above sources loosely based off your current sources.list — check it out if you want to tweak it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that 14.10 isn't maintained anymore.

I followed https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/ and it worked:

> Normal Ubuntu releases are supported for 9 months, whereas LTS (Long Term Support) releases are supported for 5 years.  Once support is up for the version of Ubuntu you are using the repository is moved to another server and will no longer be available on the standard   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dist/ location.
>
> Run this command below on your server and it will replace all of the  archive.ubuntu.com  and  security.ubuntu.com package repository URLs with  old-releases.ubuntu.com

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main universe
```

Comment: I also had to get rid of the country mirror prefix, e.g.: `s/gb.//`. Thanks for figuring this out!