# 404 Not Found for do-release-upgrade in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 15.10

I'm using Ubuntu 15, and I'm trying to get Ubuntu 16. I was getting some 404 errors with `sudo apt-get update`, so I already looked into threads such as these

[404 failed to fetch package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572235/404-failed-to-fetch-package)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316812/ubuntu-apt-get-unable-to-fetch-packages

I resolved the errors by editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file so it looks like

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
#deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main
#deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main
```

However, when I try `sudo do-release-upgrade`, I get 404 errors such as

```
...
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
  404  Not Found                                                               
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386     Packages         
  404  Not Found                                                               
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
  404  Not Found 

...

Error authenticating some packages 

It was not possible to authenticate some packages. This may be a transient network problem. You may want to try again later. See below  for a list of unauthenticated packages. 

apt-xapian-index 
libboost-graph-parallel1.58.0 
libboost-mpi-python1.58.0 
libboost-mpi1.58.0 
virtualbox 
virtualbox-qt
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: Disable IPv6 in Network Settings.

Comment: @zacharee, I just disabled IPv6 and tried `sudo do-release-upgrade` again, but I get the same 404 errors

Comment: @florian, this is not a duplicate. I already mentioned I changed `archive` to `old-releases` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Backup and install from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at old-releases.ubuntu.com you can see that Wily is not yet there.

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/

You'll want to switch from old-releases to archive.ubuntu.com.